# can text be written in badges

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem, badge

I am writing an application in which i inform the user of some events by 2-3 letter words written in tab badges. It works fine and according to me looks fine.

The thing is; in the **iOS Human Interface Guidelines**, under the **Appearance and Behavior** section, it states:

> A tab can display a badge (a red oval that contains white text, either
>   a number or exclamation point) that communicates app-specific
>   information

What is to be understand from this? if i have letters in the badge (which is allowed by the sdk) would my application get denied? if you know of any apps in the istore can you inform me or have you tried submitting an application with similar badges?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to app approval the only thing you can do is submit it and see what Apple says. You will find people who say they have had apps that do this accepted, and you will find people that say they have had apps that do this get rejected.

If that feature is important to you, then submit it and be ready to defend your self if it is rejected.

Comment: Ok as far as i understand, since the guidelines do not specifically disallow the use of letters in a badge as seen from the statement, i can try to submit it. So even if it gets rejected, do they give me a chance to defend myself?!?

Comment: If they decline it, they will cite one or more of the reasons in the Appstore Guidelines, available here: http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html If this occurs, then you cannot say "well another app does XYZ" because this is how Apple work. You will need to either remove it or come up with an alternative solution. Best of luck!

Comment: Personally, I think the HIG is pretty clear in saying that only numbers and exclamation points are allowed, but do what you think is best. Just don't be surprised if they reject it. You can appeal, but it is very unlikely they would reverse the decision.